# Screen rotation

Tags: java, android, screen-rotation

I was writing very  simple application in Android with screen rotation. I woud like "repair" this code, because screen don't rotate.

I add code in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Rest of code:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ScreenOrientationActivity extends Activity {

      public void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      }

      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config){
          super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
          if(config.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    setContentView(R.layout.landscape);
          }

          if(config.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);


      }
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        }   
}
**EDIT:**
```

My full manifest.xml- his not have line android:screenOrientation=portrait:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ScreenOrientationActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Here is how you disable landspace http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/06/activity-screen-rotationorientation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had you added orientation=portrait in your manifest's activity tag?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it manually in onConfigChanges...
Just add a library called:
layout-land in the same level as layout and put there the layout files for landscape mode.
Android will do it automatically for you.

Read here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html